# How to intergate web application like Google Calendar?

Tags: node.js, express, calendar, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api

I'm developing web application that looks like the Google Calendar but backed end by NodeJS server. At now I need to make possible to allow users to integrate their created calendars to their sites (like as Google Calendar do).

Basically I don't understand how could I make this possible. I'm looking for any tutorials and/or examples (in Node JS especially) that could be start point.
Please give me any advice or share your experience.
Thanks.

Comment: You mean you want to import the events from Google Calendar to your custom calendar? [export them](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37111) and have a look at the [iCalendar format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this question can't be closed because there is a bounty on it, I'll add an answer to it:

### What you are looking for is called an "embeddable widget".

The idea is that you provide your end user (developer/webmaster) with a piece of javascript that will:

- If needed pull in more javascript from your server.
- Append a bunch of HTML that contains your widget into the place where it was droppeded in.
- Speak with your server through either ajax or other ways.

Here are a couple of resources for you to read:

- http://codeutopia.net/blog/2012/05/26/best-practices-for-building-embeddable-widgets/
- http://prettyprint.me/prettyprint.me/2009/05/30/widgets-iframe-vs-inline/
- http://iframely.com/docs/iframelyjs - iframe widget lib (never tried)

Comment: Thanks for the reply but in the links that you've provided I don't see oauth2 supporting. I'm very interested in integrating embedded widget with oauth2 to have access control access like Google Calendar does.

May you give me a start point in using oauth2 with embedded widget? I use Node JS on my backend.